# auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'UserManage.groups'

Tags: python, django

In my Django project I have a `user_manage` app.

I create a model named `UserManage` in my `user_manage` app's model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class UserManage(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

Then I run:

```
$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

There comes the error:

```
ERRORS:
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'UserManage.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'UserManage.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'UserManage.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'UserManage.user_permissions'.
users_management.UserManage.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'UserManage.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'UserManage.groups' or 'User.groups'.
users_management.UserManage.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'UserManage.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'UserManage.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
```

Comment: Have you mentioned `AUTH_USER_MODEL ` in `settings.py`?

Answer (score 318, accepted):

Add the following to `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users_management.UserManage"
```

More generally,

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'YourAppName.YourClassName'
```

- *YourAppName*: This is the name of the app that will have the User Model
- *YourClassName*: This is the name of the class used inside the **models.py** file

Comment: How can I add user from path like UsersManager.models.custom_user.User?

Comment: What if I need migrate first? ie: ... makemigrations users? Without AUTH_USER_MODEL I will receive the "clash" error. With AUTH_USER_MODEL: "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

Comment: To my previous comment: The reason was that inside same application with AUTH_USER_MODEL was a second model with use of get_user_model(). It was neccessary to comment out the 2nd model and make "makemigrations" in two steps.

Comment: I got this error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "user_usertable" does not exist`  with `user` is my app name and `UserTable`  is the class inside my model

Answer (score 31):

Add this in the settings :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'APPNAME.User'
```

This way we are telling Django to use our custom model instead the default one.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many StackOverflow users are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted, so will not learn from your answer.

Answer (score 12):

The solution is to first add the following line into your settings.py-

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL="myproject.User"
```

Where myproject is your project name.
If you again get error then run following commands in your main directory-

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 10):

Add this setting.py
`AUTH_USER_MODEL = "myapp.User"`

Comment: The answer is identical to the already accepted one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49189522/5537876

Answer (score 8):

Add this in the settings at the end of the code :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL="users.CustomUser"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `AUTH_USER_MODEL="your app name.User"` in `settings.py` as shown in the code below

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
AUTH_USER_MODEL="myproject.User"
    
# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
    
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If above steps don´t work, delete all migrations history and your database.

Then "makemigrations" and "migrate" like it was for the first time.

The User model must be created at beginning of the project, before firts migration.