# Django multiple user types migration error

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a multiple user types using Django Abstract User but whenever I try to migrate the changes it gives me an error. As I'm still new to Django, I don't understand that it means

Here is my models code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
   is_customer = models.BooleanField(default = False)
   is_seller = models.BooleanField(default = False)
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
```

And whenever I try to migrate this model I get this error:

**ERRORS:
Accounts.CustomUser.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Accounts.CustomUser.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Accounts.CustomUser.groups' or 'auth.User.groups'.
Accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions' or 'auth.User.user_permissions'.
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Accounts.CustomUser.groups'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.groups' or 'Accounts.CustomUser.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.user_permissions' or 'Accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions'.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `settings.py`

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "Accounts.CustomUser"
```

In General :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "YourAppName.YourClassName"
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189402/auth-user-groups-fields-e304-reverse-accessor-for-user-groups-clashes-with) is the reference.