# ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am deploying a Django 1.10 project onto an Ubuntu server with Apache and mod_wsgi. I am getting the following 500 error which I can't solve:

> RuntimeError: Model class
>   django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an
>   explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

installed_apps in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'dashboard',
]
```

wsgi.py:

```
sys.path.append('/home/x_dashboard/x_dashboard/')

activate_this = os.path.expanduser("/home/x_dashboard/.venv/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/home/x_dashboard/x_dashboard/.python-egg'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'x_dashboard.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   #ServerName example.com
   #ServerAlias www.example.com
   #ServerAdmin username@example.com

   DocumentRoot /home/x_dashboard/x_dashboard/

   #ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/error.log
   #CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/access.log combined

   WSGIScriptAlias / /home/x_dashboard/x_dashboard/x_dashboard/wsgi_local.py

   #Alias /robots.txt /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/robots.txt
   #Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/favicon.ico
   #Alias /images /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/images
   Alias /static /var/www/x_dashboard/static

   <Directory /home/x_dashboard/x_dashboard/x_dashboard/>
     <Files wsgi.py>
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
     Require all granted
     </Files>
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#app-label) says that an app_label is required for models which do not belong to an app defined in installed_apps. However,  'django.contrib.contenttypes' *is* defined in installed_apps.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Answer (score 5):

Try running the following commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

This solved the issue on my side.

Comment: What if I don't have any pending migrations?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else struggling with this bug: I solved it by moving 'django.contrib.contenttypes', to the top of my installed_apps list in settings.py.

I also moved

```
import django
django.setup()
```

to after installed_apps. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206569/django-model-doesnt-declare-an-explicit-app-label) was helpful.

Comment: In my case it was that an app (django-rosetta) listed in INSTALLED_APPS wasn't installed (pip install) in the virtual environment.

Comment: @eli what is means `import django django.setup()` and where did u implemented it.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure to set up your env var: `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project_dir.settings.local`.

[image]