# AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to query data from database using Python shell. `settings.py` includes:

```
import django
django.setup()

...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products.apps.ProductsConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
]
```

When i open Python shell i do:

```
> from django.conf import settings
> settings.configure()
```

Then I try to import models:

```
> from products.models import Product
```

However, Python returns:

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

I tried [adding `django.setup()` call in settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114427/django-upgrading-to-1-9-error-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet) and also [moving this statement after `INSTALLED_APPS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811031/contenttype-doesnt-declare-an-explicit-app-label).

EDIT: With `django.setup()` I get the following error when I try to run command `runserver`:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

Comment: There is a special command for that https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#shell . No need to do any extra setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, django hasn't been properly initialized and so you are getting this message.

As @davit-tovmasyan mentioned, there is a built in `manage.py` command to open a django shell in the correct context:

```
./manage.py shell
```

Additionally, if you install [django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) there is a *very* helpful command which imports all your models, plus common imports:

```
$ ./manage.py shell_plus

# Shell Plus Model Imports
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from project.my_app.models import Model1, Model2
# ...etc, for all django and project apps
# Shell Plus Django Imports
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.conf import settings
# ...
>>> type your python here
```

If you want to run your own script, for example in `temp.py`, then you can copy the manage.py code into a new file and run it directly:

```
import os
import django

# these must be before any other imports of django app code/models
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
django.setup() 

from my_app.models import Product
print(Product.objects.all())

# at the command line:
$> chmod +x temp.py
$> ./tmp.py
```

Also, with [django-extensions run_script](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html), is the `scripts` folder where you can add simple python scripts with a `run()` method.