# RuntimeError: Model class nose.util.C doesn't declare an explicit app_label

Tags: django, nose

What is causing this error in my django app only when I run unit tests?  Why does it think `nose.util.C` is a model?

> RuntimeError: Model class nose.util.C doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded.

Comment: I can't comment, but I added my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56723920/1305080 because it sounded like that wasn't actually solved and this and that _might_ be the same issue as mine.

Answer (score 6):

You may have a model that has Test in its name.  Nose is wrapping the class and confusing Django.

[jwhitlock on github explains,](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose/issues/249#issuecomment-165671612)

> My current guess is that nose is detecting a model class that it thinks it should run tests - maybe because it is named Test, or TestFoo, or FooTest, and it wrapping it in transplant_class, which is freaking out Django's model loader. If this is the case, it may work if you rename the class, or don't do Python path manipulations, or add a __test__= False class declaration.

The other alternative is to use `@nottest` from `nose.tools` to decorate the class:

```
from nose.tools import nottest

@nottest
class Testacean(Model):
    ...
```