# Error while creating a view and displays some errors which goes like explicit label and isn't inside the INSTALLED APPS

Tags: python, django, django-models

the Entire error message is:

```
Exception ignored in thread started by: <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001967F417820>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 356, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "c:\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\src\trydjango\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from src.products.views import product_detail_view
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\src\products\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import Product
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\src\products\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Product(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\ALEX GEORGE\Dev\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 115, in __new__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Model class src.products.models.Product doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I have used the solution which was mentioned earlier like using  'django.contrib.sites' and setting SITE ID =1, But Im still getting the same error. My setting goes like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # own
    'pages',
    'products'
]
SITE_ID = 1;
```

I got this error while i created a product directory inside a template directory and I named the template as product.html. My apps name is products. enter code here
Here is my model

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)  # max_length is required
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10000)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    featured = models.BooleanField()  # null=True, default= True
```

here is my view inside products

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product


# Create your views here.
def product_detail_view(request):
    obj = Product.objects.get(id=1)
    context = {
        'title': obj.title,
        'description': obj.description
    }
    return render(request, "product/detail.html", context)
```

here is my pages apps view

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    print(request.user)
    #  return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello World</h1>")  # html string code
    return render(request, "home.html")


def contact_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "contact.html")


def about_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    my_context = {
        "my_text": "This is about us",
        "my_number": 123,
        "my_list": [123, 3223, 1323]
    }
    return render(request, "about.html", my_context)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your products/views.py you should write

```
from products.models import Product
```

instead of

```
from .models import Product
```

And restart the server

And if you still getting error try this
[AppConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40206661/12261752)

Comment: I tried adding from products.models import Product . This in not working