# Django model class error when adding a new class into models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following code:

**models.py**

```
    from django.db import models

    class Title(models.Model):
        title_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        category = models.CharField(max_length= 30)

    class Tags(models.Model):
        tag1 = models.CharField(max_length=15)
        tag2 = models.CharField(max_length=15)
        tag3 = models.CharField(max_length=15)
        tag4 = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    class Videos:
        primo: str
```

**views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from .models import Videos

    def home(request):
        vid = Videos()
        vid.primo = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'vid': vid})
```

**settings.py**

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]
```

When I run the server I get: RuntimeError: Model class home.models.Title doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Everything was working before adding class Videos() and just using:

```
    def home(request):
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

I don't understand what I should specify in the INSTALLED_APPS as I just added a new def to render a video URL inside my HTML. Why I get this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you return `{'vid': vid})` object. do you meant to return `{'vid': vid.primo})` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206569/django-model-doesnt-declare-an-explicit-app-label

Comment: @Subham  yes, I meant that, thanks. It doesn't solve the error though

Comment: @ Aadesh yes, I saw it but I don't understand why I should add that to the list of installed apps.