# Django - account.models.Account doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS while using pinax-notifications

Tags: django, pinax

Integrating client project with pinax-notifications for notification kind of functionality.

```
  *File "/home/user/Shwetha/ramble/ramble/rambleapp/urls.py", line 56, in <module>
    url(r"^notifications/", include("pinax.notifications.urls", namespace="pinax_notifications")),
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pinax/notifications/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .views import NoticeSettingsView
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pinax/notifications/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .compat import login_required
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pinax/notifications/compat.py", line 12, in <module>
    from account.decorators import login_required
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/account/decorators.py", line 5, in <module>
    from account.utils import handle_redirect_to_login
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/account/utils.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .models import PasswordHistory
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/account/models.py", line 26, in <module>
    class Account(models.Model):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 116, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class account.models.Account doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.*
```

As per the https://github.com/pinax/pinax-notifications#documentation Documentation , it was installed and configured. Encountered the above error while configuring.

Already tried:

1. In settings.py, INSTALLED_APPS section add both pinax and pinax-notifications.
2. Added Sites in INSTALLED_APPS and made SITE_ID=1 in settings.py.
3. verbose_name added in apps.py.

All the above does not seem to solve the problem. Please advise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62772698/11282077 this would help I hope

Comment: The model in the error is in `account/models.py` that does not look like the package you link to. Pinax is trying to import that in a try-except (expecting an import error) in case you are using [django-user-accounts](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts) (another package from pinax). You import succeeds as perhaps you have installed that app or some other with a similar name. The problem is this app is not in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Likely the problem is you aren't using a virtual environment for your python projects.

Comment: I tried now. That Class Meta : app_label = "name_of_your_app" is not working.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat 
INSTALLED_APPS:
    'myapp',
    'pinax',
    'pinax.notifications',

Comment: myapp has  views, models, templates and signals at the same level. Signals has the handlers.py which create notice types. 

apps.py is as follows:
`from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate

from myapp.signals import handlers

class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
    verbose_name = 'myapp'
    
    def ready(self):
        post_migrate.connect(handlers.create_notice_types, sender=self)`

Comment: Adding 'account' to the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py solved the problem! Thanks everyone.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Solved.