# RuntimeError: Model doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing, django-settings, django-tests

I am writing an app in Django and I'm trying to do some unit testing
but I can't seem to find why the test is failing
that is the test page:

```
import re
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from . import models



class BasicTests(TestCase):

    def test_firstname(self):
        print('test11')
        acc = models.Accounts()
        acc.first_name = 'Moran'
        self.assertTrue(len(acc.id) <= 9, 'Check name is less than 50 digits long')
        self.assertFalse(len(acc.id) > 50, 'Check name is less than 50 digits long')
```

the error i get is :

> RuntimeError: Model class DoggieSitter.accounts.models.Accounts
> doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in
> INSTALLED_APPS

thats my installed app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts'
]
```

Comment: Looks like the installed app should be `DoggieSitter.accounts` based on the error. How are you running the test and where from?

Comment: I am running the command
"python manage.py test"
from the terminal

Comment: Have you tried adding `DoggieSitter.accounts` to your INSTALLED_APPS setting instead of `accounts`?

Comment: Yes I did but there was an erro"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DoggieSitter'"
Moreover I was unable to upload the site add more issues unrelated to the testing

Comment: Hello @ShTurj try to add full app location eg. ***(accounts.apps.AccountsConfig)*** inside your INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: I am a bit new to the Django framework To add to the installed app Doggiesitter.accounts.Accountsconfig Where the Accounts is the class name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django model "doesn't declare an explicit app\_label"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206569/django-model-doesnt-declare-an-explicit-app-label)

Comment: i tried and it didn't work to for me

Answer (score 1):

Try changing line 4 above to an explicit import such as `from DoggieSitter.accounts import models`

I had this problem whenever running tests where the `tests.py` had a relative import such `from .models import ModelName`. After searching for an hour or so, I stumbled on [this answer to exactly the tutorial I was following](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/comments/6374/).

In my case, I was trying `from .models import Recipe`. My project structure is as below, so I changed to `from apps.recipes.models import Recipe` and the test now runs fine. It's a shame because I'd prefer to keep using relative imports.

```
src
├── __init__.py
├── apps
│   ├── accounts
│   ├── core
│   └── recipes
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── ... etc
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── secrets
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── base
│   │   └── development
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── utilities.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── static
└── templates
```

PS - another even more explicit way that also seems to work is:

```
from django.apps import apps
Recipe = apps.get_model(app_label='recipes', model_name='Recipe')
```

... but I think I prefer the simpler explicit import statement.