# Sphinx with Django - Model doesn't declare an explicit app label

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-sphinx

I have spent countless hours but this is still stuck. The documentation is so lacking. Using Django 1.10, trying to create Sphinx documentation which has been giving various errors. Finally I am stuck here. I created an example model in my main app `kyc_connect` as below.

## Models.py

```
from django.db import models
class example(models.Model):        
    filed1 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # class Meta:
    #     app_label = 'kyc_connect'
```

Running `make_html` gives the below error.

`RuntimeError: Model class kyc_connect.models.example doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

## Conf.py import settings

```
import os
import sys    
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
import django
django.setup()
```

When I include `Meta` class presently commented out, this errors goes away. 
But if I include a model with `ForeignKey` and import `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` it gives error `RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

## INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'kyc_connect',
    'kyc_connect_data_models',
    'kyc_rest_services.kyc_connect_accounts',
    'kyc_rest_services.kyc_connect_documents',
    'kyc_rest_services.kyc_connect_transaction_manager',
    'tasks',
    'elasticstack',
    'corsheaders',
    'haystack'
]
```

## ProjectStructure

```
kyc_connect:
  -config
  -docs
  -kyc_connect
    -models.py
    .
    .
  -kyc_connect_data_models
  -kyc_core
  -kyc_rest_services
    -kyc_connect_accounts
    -kyc_connect_transaction_manager
    .
    .
  .
  .
```

I already have `django.contrib.contentype` there. But django doesn't seem to understand. I don't want to declare meta class. What is going wrong. Any help would be great.

Comment: Did you run `makemigratoin` and `migrate`?

Comment: No, I am not even aware how it is dependent on that, let me try.

Comment: `No changes detected`. My models are already in db. Though added `example` model just for checking.

Comment: Do you import your `kyc_connect` app somewhere? If so and if that import is made *before* your models are loaded, this error also occurs.

Comment: I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388637/runtimeerror-model-class-django-contrib-sites-models-site-doesnt-declare-an-ex) where the solution was to add `'django.contrib.sites'` to your installed apps. You may give it a try.

Comment: No that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my project and ended up resolving it by removing the `settings.configure()` in my conf.py file and running

```
make clean
make html
```

in my docs directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in my project. I resolved it by changing how I import the model in all my app files. For example to register the model in admin.py change

```
from project.app.models import YourModel
```

*to..*

```
from .models import Your.Model
```

Answer (score 0):

For others who are still struggling with this issue, this may help:

please pay attention to have:

```
.. automodule:: appName.models
```

and not something like:

```
.. automodule:: ProjectName.appName.models
```

could append if like me you prefer, for some reasons, to have your `docs` directory in the parent folder of your django root directory.

**Note:** For working properly, my views and tasks must be set with:

```
.. automodule:: ProjectName.appName.tasks
.. automodule:: ProjectName.appName.views
```

Hope it will save time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace

```
settings.configure()
```

with

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'ProjectName.settings',
```

then check `abspath()` here:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

so it should lead to parent dir for "docs" folder,

then check `index.rst`

```
.. automodule:: appName.tasks
```