# ImportError: Failed to import test module:

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing, django-settings

im having an issue with a tutorial im following. we have gotten to the point of testing and i continue to get an error when running

```
python manage.py test
```

Here is my error:

```
(restapi) chrismaltez@Chriss-MacBook-Pro:~/Desktop/pycharmprojects/UDEMY/restapi/src$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
..E
======================================================================
ERROR: src.status.tests (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: src.status.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 428, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/chrismaltez/Desktop/pycharmprojects/UDEMY/restapi/src/status/tests.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .models import Status
  File "/Users/chrismaltez/Desktop/pycharmprojects/UDEMY/restapi/src/status/models.py", line 20, in <module>
    class Status(models.Model): #fb status, instagram post, tween, linkedin post
  File "/Users/chrismaltez/Desktop/pycharmprojects/UDEMY/restapi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 118, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class src.status.models.Status doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.096s
```

I dont understand why i get this error because i have status in the installed apps here:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',

        #third party
        'rest_framework',

        #local
        'accounts',
        'status',
        'updates',
    ]
```

and then here is my models that its saying i am having an error with:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


def upload_status_image(instance, filename):
    return "status/{user}/{filename}".format(user=instance.user, filename=filename)


class StatusQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    pass

class StatusManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return StatusQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)


# Create your models here.
class Status(models.Model): #fb status, instagram post, tween, linkedin post
    user            = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) # user instance .save
    content         = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    image           = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_status_image, null=True, blank=True) # great 3rd part package = django storanges --> AWS#pip install pillow to handle images
    updated         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = StatusManager

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.content)[:50]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Status post"
        verbose_name_plural = "Status posts"


    @property
    def owner(self):
        return self.user
```

i'm running on a Mac in django 1.11.8.

When i run makemigrations, i get no errors. when i runserver, i get no errors. i've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388637/runtimeerror-model-class-django-contrib-sites-models-site-doesnt-declare-an-ex) but nothing has worked.

Any and all help is appreciated.

-update-
filetree:

```
restapi
|-bin
|-include
|-lib
|-scripts
|-src
  |-accounts
  |  |-api
  |  |  |-user
  |  |  |  |-__init__.py
  |  |  |  |-serializers.py
  |  |  |  |-urls.py
  |  |  |  |-views.py
  |  |  |-__init__.py
  |  |  |-permissions.py
  |  |  |-serializers.py
  |  |  |-test_user_api.py
  |  |  |-urls.py
  |  |  |-utils.py
  |  |  |-views.py
  |  |-+migrations
  |  |-__init__.py
  |  |-admin.py
  |  |-apps.py
  |  |-models.py
  |  |-tests.py
  |  |-views.py
  |-cfeapi
  |  |-restconf
  |  |  |-__init__.py
  |  |  |-main.py
  |  |  |-pagination.py
  |  |-__init__.py
  |  |-mixins.py
  |  |-settings.py
  |  |-urls.py
  |  |-wsgi.py
  |-status
    |-api    
    |  |-__init__.py
    |  |-serializers.py
    |  |-urls.py
    |  |-views.py
    |+migrations
    |-__init__.py
    |-admin.py
    |-apps.py
    |-forms.py
    |-models.py
    |-tests.py
    |-views.py
```

Comment: Are you sure your PyCharm points to the right root directory? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304044/pycharm-current-working-directory?rq=1

Comment: You have `'status'` (without the `src` prefix) in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, therefore it should be importing the model as `status.models.Status`, but the error shows `src.status.models.Status`. If you show the layout of the files in your project it might indicate what the problem is. If there is an `__init__.py` in the `src` directory, then try removing it.

Comment: Add a tree view of your project directory structure.

Comment: is there an easy way to copy the tree view from pycharm besides taking a snippet? everytime i make a project tree for stack overflow, it takes a decent amount of time.

i just did a quick search but didnt see anything promising.

Comment: took a while but i added the tree view

Comment: @Alasdair i tried removing the __init__.py file and running the tests but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: You can use the `tree` command to display the project layout. On a Mac, you can install it using `brew`.

Comment: @Alasdair, just got it working. its a huge time saver. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this issue where I got the ModuleNotFoundError for a folder in my path that I wasn't directly specifying.

I was running my test file inside PyCharm.

The fix was adding the main entry point to my test file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Got the same scenario but problem persists :(

Answer (score 6):

i figured it out after more crawling on stackO. It was a simple fix I got the idea from here:
[website w/ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388637/runtimeerror-model-class-django-contrib-sites-models-site-doesnt-declare-an-ex)
. it turns out the answer was just to change the relative import to an abolute import

In status/tests.py, the line of code had to change from:

```
from .models import Status
```

to:

```
from status.models import Status
```

I still find it weird that it threw an error but the accounts/tests.py is fine.

Comment: I am also facing this error but doing the opposite to what you did here solved my issue. Idk why(very new to django).

Answer (score 3):

Also **the test package should not have the same name as the source package**. Eg:

```
- src
 - utils
  - utilities.py
- tests
 - utils
  - test_utilities.py
```

This setup can cause the error, although it depends on your PYTHONPATH and where you run the tests from. Note how there's `utils` package in both `src` and `test` directories. Renaming one of the packages seems to solve the problem, eg: `utils` and `test_utils`.

Not directly the situation that OP is facing, but I thought it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error because I had an `__init__.py` file in the root directory.

Comment: Dude! Thank You so much for this comment! Same thing in our project! :3

Answer (score 0):

Try such as `python manage.py test --pattern="*_models.py"`

Answer (score 0):

Double check you pycharm root directory also, if you did put your virtual environment to the same directory as django apps, move env file to higher hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

So I got this error because I had an `__init__.py` file in the same directory as the project root (the same directory that manage.py exists in.)  This caused some wierd import issues with the tests code and caused a number of other imports of tests to fail.