# Django: Model class __main__.Source doesn't declare an explicit app_label when loading a model in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I used to load models in Python shell in PyCharm with no error before, but now it through this error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 112, in __new__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Model class __main__.Source doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I checked similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206569/django-model-doesnt-declare-an-explicit-app-label) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388637/runtimeerror-model-class-django-contrib-sites-models-site-doesnt-declare-an-ex) and followed the proposed answers with no success. Funny thing is that `python manage.py runserver` doesn't through any error and website load smoothly.

The only change to my environment is that update for windows I got yesterday.

I already have app name for all of my apps, set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and all imports are absolute.

Comment: If you are deploying to a remote server, try uploading your entire django project.  If you are not deploying to a remote server you might want to remove all your `*pyc` files.

Comment: It works just fine when I deploy it to a remote server, it also works fine with py manage.py runserver command. The only problem is when I'm trying to run it in python shell for debugging.

Comment: How are you starting you python console?

Comment: @RedCricket I'm using PyCharm. Probably it's a mistake after long hours of trying to solve something that is not a real problem. I tried to load the model definition and got this error. But then I tried ``` from appname.models import modelname ``` and it worked. sorry for posting a wrong question!